# httpwebrequest giving false results

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

```
 if (IsURLValid(url))
            {
                Uri requestUri = new Uri(url);
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                httpWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                httpWebRequest.Timeout = 3000;
                httpWebRequest.Method = "HEAD";
                //httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
                httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                httpWebResponse.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(httpWebResponse.ResponseUri.ToString());
                if ((httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) || (httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect))
                {

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above code is working good however its giving some false results. The below url is live however the result we are getting is invalid.

### https://forum.unity.com/threads/clean-way-to-talk-to-external-application-c-to-ros-c-node.418849/

I have tried online checker also, those checkers also giving same error.
https://httpstatus.io/
check the unity url in httpstatus its giving error. ANy one have idea why it is like that?

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting? Also, I think the `else` block is quite unnecessary.

Comment: The url is valid but still code its returning false. I want to get exactly valid urls.

Comment: How about not calling response.Close() unitl you've actually evaluated the response?

Comment: Not working. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Otherwise your `(HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();` will throw an exception and you will get the `return false;` from your catch statement.

See [this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024657/cookiecontainer-confusion)